# Overstayed my visa by 1 year and 5 months 14 years ago. Would like to visit for 20 days. Do I need to apply for a visa?

Tags: visas, overstaying, slovakia, slovak-citizens

I am a Slovak citizen with Slovak passport, and UK resident with settled status. I live and work in the UK. I have a mortgage, children go to school here. Do I apply for a visa in Slovakia?

Comment: If you're a Slovak citizen, you don't need a visa to visit your own country, surely?

Comment: @dda note tag, It looks like a US visa is wanted. OP can you make it clear which country you want to visit and that it's the country you overstayed in? Did you leave voluntarily or were you deported?

Comment: @mkennedy Nicely spotted thanks!

Comment: How did you leave? By plane or via a land border?

Comment: Are you considering an application for a visa to enter the US?

Comment: The tags have been edited to reflect the body of the question. Please edit to add the country you want to visit.